# Python Config parser read comment along with value

Tags: python, configparser

I have config file,

```
[local]
    variable1 : val1 ;#comment1
    variable2 : val2 ;#comment2
```

code like this reads only value of the key:

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read('config.py')

    def get_path(self):
        return self.config.get('local', 'variable1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Config()
    print c.get_path()
```

but i also want to read the comment present along with the value, any suggestions in this regards will be very helpful.

Comment: updated the question, it was a typo, commments in the file is using ; character followed by # character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only solutions is to write another `ConfigParser` overriding the method `_read()`. In your `ConfigParser` you should delete all checks about comment removal. This is a **dangerous solution**, but should work.

```
class ValuesWithCommentsConfigParser(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):

    def _read(self, fp, fpname):
        from ConfigParser import DEFAULTSECT, MissingSectionHeaderError, ParsingError

        cursect = None                        # None, or a dictionary
        optname = None
        lineno = 0
        e = None                              # None, or an exception
        while True:
            line = fp.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            lineno = lineno + 1
            # comment or blank line?
            if line.strip() == '' or line[0] in '#;':
                continue
            if line.split(None, 1)[0].lower() == 'rem' and line[0] in "rR":
                # no leading whitespace
                continue
                # continuation line?
            if line[0].isspace() and cursect is not None and optname:
                value = line.strip()
                if value:
                    cursect[optname].append(value)
            # a section header or option header?
            else:
                # is it a section header?
                mo = self.SECTCRE.match(line)
                if mo:
                    sectname = mo.group('header')
                    if sectname in self._sections:
                        cursect = self._sections[sectname]
                    elif sectname == DEFAULTSECT:
                        cursect = self._defaults
                    else:
                        cursect = self._dict()
                        cursect['__name__'] = sectname
                        self._sections[sectname] = cursect
                        # So sections can't start with a continuation line
                    optname = None
                # no section header in the file?
                elif cursect is None:
                    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
                # an option line?
                else:
                    mo = self._optcre.match(line)
                    if mo:
                        optname, vi, optval = mo.group('option', 'vi', 'value')
                        optname = self.optionxform(optname.rstrip())
                        # This check is fine because the OPTCRE cannot
                        # match if it would set optval to None
                        if optval is not None:
                            optval = optval.strip()
                            # allow empty values
                            if optval == '""':
                                optval = ''
                            cursect[optname] = [optval]
                        else:
                            # valueless option handling
                            cursect[optname] = optval
                    else:
                        # a non-fatal parsing error occurred.  set up the
                        # exception but keep going. the exception will be
                        # raised at the end of the file and will contain a
                        # list of all bogus lines
                        if not e:
                            e = ParsingError(fpname)
                        e.append(lineno, repr(line))
            # if any parsing errors occurred, raise an exception
        if e:
            raise e

        # join the multi-line values collected while reading
        all_sections = [self._defaults]
        all_sections.extend(self._sections.values())
        for options in all_sections:
            for name, val in options.items():
                if isinstance(val, list):
                    options[name] = '\n'.join(val)
```

In the `ValuesWithCommentsConfigParser` I fixed some imports and deleted the appropriate sections of code.

Using the same `config.ini` from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110661/371457), I can prove the previous code is correct.

```
config = ValuesWithCommentsConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
assert config.get('local', 'variable1') == 'value1 ; comment1'
assert config.get('local', 'variable2') == 'value2 # comment2'
```

Answer (score 8):

Alas, this is not easily done in general case. Comments are *supposed* to be ignored by the parser.

In your specific case, it is easy, because `#` only serves as a comment character if it begins a line. So variable1's value will be `"val1 #comment1"`. I suppose you use something like this, only less brittle:

```
val1_line = c.get('local', 'var1')
val1, comment = val1_line.split(' #')
```

If the value of a 'comment' is needed, probably it is not a proper comment? Consider adding explicit keys for the 'comments', like this:

```
[local]
  var1: 108.5j
  var1_comment: remember, the flux capacitor capacitance is imaginary!
```

Comment: I agree - if the comment is of interest, then it really shouldn't be a comment.

Comment: liked your answer so +1, but unfortunately, i can't modify the config file :(

Comment: After a bit of exploration I've updated the answer; maybe it's more helpful now.

Answer (score 2):

Accordiing to the [ConfigParser module](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) documentation,

> Configuration files may include comments, prefixed by specific
>   characters (# and ;). Comments may appear on their own in an otherwise
>   empty line, or may be entered in lines holding values or section
>   names. In the latter case, they need to be preceded by a whitespace
>   character to be recognized as a comment. (For backwards compatibility,
>   only ; starts an inline comment, while # does not.)

If you want to read the "comment" with the value, you can omit the whitespace before the `;` character or use the `#`. But in this case the strings `comment1` and `comment2` become part of the value and are not considered comments any more.

A better approach would be to use a different property name, such as `variable1_comment`, or to define another section in the configuration dedicated to comments:

```
[local]
    variable1 = value1
[comments]
    variable1 = comment1
```

The first solution requires you to generate a new key using another one (i.e. compute `variable1_comment` from `variable1`), the other one allows you to use the same key targeting different sections in the configuration file.

As of Python 2.7.2, **is always possibile to read a comment along the line** if you use the `#` character. As the docs say, it's for backward compatibility. The following code should run smoothly:

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
assert config.get('local', 'variable1') == 'value1'
assert config.get('local', 'variable2') == 'value2 # comment2'
```

for the following `config.ini` file:

```
[local]
variable1 = value1 ; comment1
variable2 = value2 # comment2
```

If you adopt this solution, remember to manually parse the result of `get()` for values and comments.

Comment: the config file comes to me as an input from another source which i can't control..

Comment: updated the question, it was a typo, commments in the file is using `;` character

Answer (score 1):

according to the manuals:
Lines beginning with '#' or ';' are ignored and may be used to provide comments.

so the value of variable1 is "val1 #comment1".The comment is part of the value

you can check your config whether you put a Enter before your comment

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes along afterwards. My situation was I needed to read in a .ini file generated by a Pascal Application. That configparser didn't care about # or ; starting the keys.
For example the .ini file would look like this

```
  [KEYTYPE PATTERNS]
  ##-######=CLAIM
```

Python's configparser would skip that key value pair. Needed to modify the configparser to not look at # as comments

```
  config = configparser.ConfigParser(comment_prefixes="")
  config.read("thefile")
```

I'm sure I could set the comment_prefixes to whatever Pascal uses for comments, but didn't see any, so I set it to an empty string